# Pass php variale to Javascript function

Tags: php, javascript

This is my example which not work.

```
     return ' 
<div onmousedown="displayDate('.$linkurl.')">
<embed src="'.$thead->image_url.'" allowScriptAccess="always"></embed>
</div>
       ';
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working? Any errors displaying, output incorrect...

Comment: function not get argument

Comment: Is this a return of php or javascript ? If its for php then everything seems correct and of its JS then its wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a string, it must be quoted like so:

```
return ' 
<div onmousedown="displayDate(\''.$linkurl.'\')">
<embed src="'.$thead->image_url.'" allowScriptAccess="always"></embed>
</div>
       ';
```

Answer (score 2):

Some Times sigle quote under sigle quote  double quote may crate problem try this.

```
$data =  "<div onmousedown= 'displayDate('" . $linkurl . " ')'>";

$data .=  "<embed src='" .$thead->image_url. " ' allowScriptAccess='always'></embed></div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the lack of information I can't be sure but from what I can see, your code looks correct. The only reason for this not to pass the variables properly would be if they were empty.

Add some debugging in to make sure that you have values in your variables before assigning them to the JS. You can do this by `echo`ing out the variables beforehand.